# File google-services.json is missing. where to find this file ? PHONEGAP

Tags: push-notification, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-pushplugin

**NOTE !!**

---

before declare it as duplicate :

i have found so many similar questions on stackoverflow , but the majority of askers seems to know where to find the file , i don't . they mention `gradle` and such things which i know nothing about !

---

**My question**

---

i am working on a phonegap project . i don't have any experience in android development .

after installing push plugin on my project and trying to build the project using `phonegap build android` . i get this error :

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin
>   cannot function without it.

even the [documentation](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md) of the plugin say that i have to get a `google-services.json` file and put it in my phonegap project folder .

> As of version 2.0.0 the SENDER_ID parameter has been removed at
>   install time. Instead you put your google-services.json (Android)
>   and/or GoogleService-Info.plist in the root folder of your project and
>   then add the following lines into your config.xml.

the main problem is that i have no idea where to find the `google-services.json`  and how can i get it updated with a `SENDER_ID` and other google API variables .

**Extra info**:

i am using phonegap on linux mint , i have an installed android studio .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the google-services.json from [firebase developer console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).

Click your application, here the application name is testapp

[image]

Next you will find this screen click on the menu you will see settings click on it.

[image: screen 2]

In setting you will be able to see the "Download Google-services.json" button.

[image: screen 3]

There you will find the google-services.json file for your existing project.

Hope this helps.